# Moodle 2.6 mailer not working properly

Tags: moodle

I'm having trouble with moodle mailer , problem is that moodle is not sending mail after registration to student and when somebody click forgotten password mail doesnt come to user also.

Error logs are empty

I tried to change to send via smtp servers but is not working 
My moodle version is 2.6.1 and i cannot upgrade to higher version.
Can somebody please help me with this trouble ?

This is error log:
Error code: filenotfound

```
* line 463 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
* line 1948 of /lib/filelib.php: call to print_error()
* line 1201 of /lib/outputlib.php: call to send_file_not_found()
* line 94 of /theme/essential/lib.php: call to theme_config->setting_file_serve()
* line 4628 of /lib/filelib.php: call to theme_essential_pluginfile()
* line 37 of /pluginfile.php: call to file_pluginfile()
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling developer level for debug messages?

Comment: double check you haven't got this in your config.php file `$CFG->noemailever = true;` - it's often used when developing but needs to be removed or set to false on a production server.

Comment: @RussellEngland I don't have this in config.php , the problem is that mail works with gmail.com , gmx.com etc. It's not working with smaller mail polish providers like wp.pl , o2.pl, op.pl etc..

Answer (score 0):

Edit your config.php and enter this

```
$CFG->debugsmtp = true;
```

Or go to site admin -> development -> debugging -> and check 'Debug email sending'

It will show verbose messages when sending email so might show what's wrong.

Alternatively, use an editor with xdebug enabled (I use Netbeans IDE) - then add a breakpoint at the start of the function email_to_user() in /lib/moodlelib.php - Then step through until it fails.

Comment: ok i'll try , can you tell me why i have 404 error with no debug message ?

Comment: @RusselEngland this is my error:
SMTP connect() failed

Comment: Do you need to log into the smtp host? You'll need to set the security, username and password here `/admin/settings.php?section=messagesettingemail` or go to site admin -> plugins -> message outputs -> email

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved
I had to set port in lib/moodlelib.php to 465 (My provider want me to use 587)